# Filter a vector based on approximate multiple values

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, approximate, near

Suppose I want to filter vector `x` based on which values appear *approximately* in vector `y`:

```r
x <- c(1.123456789, 2.123456789, 3.123456789)
y <- c(1.12345, 2.12345)
```

If I didn't want approximate comparison, I'd use `%in%`:

```r
x %in% y
```

> ```
> [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE
> ```

Where my required result is:

```r
# something like: x %near_in% y
```

> ```
> [1] TRUE TRUE FALSE
> ```

The `dplyr::near(x, y, tol)` function's help file mentions "x, y: Numeric vectors to compare", but this is of course not entirely true, `y` has to be either of `x`'s length or a single value, because all `near()` does is use the `abs()` function:

```r
near <- function (x, y, tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.5) 
{
    abs(x - y) < tol
}
```

And if we do this we see `abs()` takes `y`'s values and repeats them until it needs so (not without a warning), and we get:

```r
abs(x - y)
```

> ```
> [1] 0.000006789 0.000006789 2.000006789
> Warning message:
> In x - y : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
> ```

My current solution is to use `sapply()` on `y`'s elements to create a `n x m` matrix (3 x 2 here), then use `apply()` to see if `any()` of the rows (values of `x`) has `TRUE` in it:

```r
apply(sapply(y, function(y_val) near(x, y_val, 0.0001)), 1, any)
```

> ```
> [1] TRUE TRUE FALSE
> ```

But this seems cumbersome! What if I had thousands of values in `y`, wouldn't I be creating a temporary matrix with thousands of rows? Any better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `floor` or `round` the values:

```r
tol <- 1e-5
floor(x/tol)
#> [1] 112345 212345 312345
floor(y/tol)
#> [1] 112345 212345
floor(x/tol) %in% floor(y/tol)
#> [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure. but have a look at `DescTools` library where you can find closest values:

```
library(DescTools)

y %in% sapply(x, function(i) Closest(y, i))

[1] TRUE TRUE
```